# Spring Boot + Tomcat - Microservices solution

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I'm planning to expose few microservices (~20 at this stage) using Spring Boot. I will be creating executable fat jars using the embededed Tomcat. The executable jar will be wrapped in Docker container and deployed to AWS.

In my case 20 jars will have 20 tomcat instances running at the same time. I'm concerned about the overhead of running so many tomcat instances in the production server. Is this a valid concern?

I was wondering if someone has used something similar configuration in production and can share their experience.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks
JP

Comment: I guess it does not answer my original question, Sorry. I'm still not convinced if the overhead of tomcat/servlet container and spring jars in each microservice will cause any issue as the microservices grow. BTW my artifacts are around ~15-20MB

Comment: Hi @JPSingh, did you get answer, i am also looking for the same.

Comment: @JPSingh Did you find a better way?

Answer (score 2):

We currently use AWS and Spring Cloud / Spring Boot.  Our stance is instances that require more resources receive their own EC2 instance.  Services that can be deployed using Docker are deployed to [Amazon ECS](http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).

All of our deployments are fat jars using embedded Tomcat.

Not knowing the size of what you are calling a service makes this answer a little complicated. If you are worried about Tomcat's overhead why are you running these services in Docker containers? Ease of deployment?

If you do go the route of deploying multiple services to the same Tomcat instance, I would not define your setup as a microservices based configuration.

Comment: Why Docker? - We are moving towards microservice architecture where each microservice can be deployed/developed independently. We have the CI/CD setup as well which speeds up the deployment pipeline. 

You are right, Using multiple services in a single tomcat will not get us there. So that's not an option for us.

Regarding the size of my services, the current jars are approx 20MB. On a high level, The services expose a restful json api which talk to a legacy system. No db/jms transactions are involved inside the microservices.

Comment: The reason why we moved to docker was the economics of cloud services.  We can deploy more docker containers to a single instance which utilizes more of the resources each instance.  From your description of the size of the jars it is about the same as ours.  Essentially everything is a Spring Boot/Tomcat jar deployed as a Docker container to AWS ECS clusters.   DevOps/planning for us is by far the hardest part.  Roughly 600 microservices.  We have coupled this with Spring Cloud OSS / Netflix OSS.  A side benefit of Docker is much easier testing on the developers environment.

Comment: @code Even a simple microservice is taking up 600 MB to 1 GB of Ram and we found that deploying 7-8 microservices on a single t2-large instance is also not optimum. Do you think Docker will help us in this scenario?? If yes then how? Ultimately dockers are also deployed on ec2 instance and they will further add to the memory requirement compared plain spring boot base microservice. I am looking at optimally utilizing my ec2 instance.

Comment: @Netverse Docker is not a silver bullet for getting around Ram requirements.  We have been able to use smaller amounts of Ram.  128MB to 512MB.  Docker's main savings comes from less OS overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to deploy all your services  (webapps) into one or more tomcat instances. You may not include the Tomcat into war file. Example maven/spring configuration you may find [here](http://blog.konstantinpavlov.net/2015/02/19/booting-spring-webapp/)